# "roar with laughter" is American or British?

Tags: american-english, british-english

"roar with laughter" is American or British? What is meaning of it?

Comment: It means to laugh loudly. I'm sure it is used in both American and British English (but don't know where it was first used).

Answer (score 1):

In such locutions, {intransitive verb} **with** {noun}, the object of the preposition **with** is that which causes or motivates, or informs the action expressed by the verb.

> He bounced with joy.

Joy made him bounce.

> He roared with laughter.

Laughter made him roar.

> He danced with glee.

Glee made him dance.

> He shuddered with fear.

Fear made him shudder.

> He seethed with anger.

Anger made him seethe.

The meaning is:

```
He was so joyful, he was bouncing.

He was laughing so hard and so loudly, he roared.

He was so gleeful, he was dancing.

He was so afraid, he shuddered.

He was so angry, he was seething.
```

As you can see from the examples, usually the {verb} is figurative or exaggerated.  People do not actually reach a *boil* when they are angry, and they don't actually bounce like a ball when they're happy, though they might jump up and down.

Comment: He flirted with danger.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I've qualified with "intransitive".

Comment: @Damkerng T.  I've qualified with "or informs". I understand "motivate" to mean "to cause and give shape to sth".   **With** + noun is more than a periphrasis for adverbial -ily, -ly.

Comment: He ran with difficulty.

Comment: @nnnnnn: He ran difficultly?  You need to give me more than an example of something. I'm not sure what it is you're challenging.

Comment: I was giving an example of {intransitive verb} with {noun} where the noun didn't cause the verb. Anyway, it's OK, I don't really think your explanation was meant to apply to literally every possible combination of {intransitive verb} with {noun} - I agree that it does apply to a lot of cases. "He ran difficultly" doesn't really make sense. "He ran with difficulty" does make sense.

Comment: **With** + {nominal} occupies a semantic zone between *manner* and *agency/cause*.  The manner is the result of the agency.

Comment: Well... Yes, in my example "with difficulty" is the manner in which "he ran". I'm not quite sure what you mean about the manner being the result of the agency; what if the reason why he had difficulty running was not related to why he was running? (But again, I don't expect your explanation to apply to *all* cases.)

Comment: Right, he is not running *because* he has a sprained ankle. What I'm trying to get at with *informs* is that the nominal  in these {subject}{intransitive verb}+ **with** +{nominal} locutions refers to a motivating/shaping agency akin to a cause.  **With** + nominal typically  expresses manner by reference to a state or condition that inheres in, or is attendant upon the actor {verb}ing, whereas the *-ily*, *ly* adverbs express merely the manner of the {verb}.  "He ate *with gusto*".  His enjoyment is evident.  "He ran with difficulty."  His difficulty is evident.  versus "He ran slowly".

Comment: So, is it American or British?

Comment: I've heard it used in both countries.  It sounds like an 18th century Britishism to me.